# How to give input_shape to Convolutional Neural Network if I am trying to fit the data from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have a pandas dataframe `X_train` with 733999 samples and 5 features.

```
model = Squential()    
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
             activation ='relu', input_shape = (?,?)))
```

This is the first layer where I am having trouble. 
All the tutorials have used image and they are just passing in the height, width and channel as the parameter of input_shape. I am having trouble to give the input shape in case of pandas dataframe. 
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What are those 5 features? what are your inputs for the Convolutional layer?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. A [Conv2d](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) operation expects a 4D input tensor of shape: [batch_size, rows, cols, channels]. How you plan on mapping that to your data frame, nobody here knows.

Comment: I am sorry for not providing all the information. I am asking any question on stackoverflow for the first time.

Comment: [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zZF2nGqT5FJxbaMRyYI4pEQ32axGtKmk )
This is the link to an image how my pandas dataframe looks. The image shows only 10 samples but I have a sample size of 733999 
@bleand

Comment: @MFisherKDX I am new to Convolutional Neural Network. So can't understand how i will be able to map my dataframe into the input_shape

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/). You need to understand how a convolutional layer works and need to understand its use case. You need to format your input features in a 3D tensor of shape [rows, cols, channels]. input_size needs to be 3 dimensions here. The function operates on a 4D tensor, by adding a batch_size dimension.

Comment: Convolutional networks are nice when information has a locality component to it. For example, image pixels next to each other are related -- and that locality information can be exploited by a convolutional layer. Input doesn't have to be images -- any signal where nearby points are related can be used. Since nobody here knows what your features represent, it's very hard to suggest if a convolutional layer would be appropriate or how to structure it.

Comment: I will go through it but can you please help me with the particular values I need to pass into the input_shape as of now? Then I can start to train my CNN

Comment: Based on your image I will guess that you have 5 or 6 input values and you have some sort of output for each of the rows (may be a category or a number). If that's the case, I wouldn't recommend you do that. A FeedForward will be a better fit for it. If you still want to use a CNN, check my answer for an example

Answer (score 1):

This is an example on how you can use a CNN with your data

**I still do not recommend this type of network for the data that you have**

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Reshape
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## Dummy data
data = {'0': [1, 2, 3], '1': [3, 4, 3], '2':[0,1, 3], '3':[0,1,3], '4':[0,1,3], '5':[0,1,3]}
X_train = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((1,X_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (1,5),padding = 'Same',
             activation ='relu', input_shape = (1,X_train.shape[1],1)))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (1,6), strides=(1,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense (500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense (1, activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

## Training and testing with dummy data just to prove that it's working
model.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array([0,1,1]), nb_epoch=4, validation_data=(np.array(X_train), np.array([0,1,1])))
```

Comment: thanks anyway.
It's interesting to try to classifie with a CNN to compare with keras trees etc.